# How to Export Cross Table ( ! without value formatting ! ) to Excel in SPotfire ( IronPython Script )

Tags: ironpython, spotfire, tibco, spotfire-webplayer, spotfire-analyst

Good morning,

I can extract a report in CSV format and put it in my directory with the following code underneath. The only problem is that I want to extract it without value formatting.

```
enter from System.IO import Path, File, StreamWriter
      from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import TablePlot
      from System.IO import Path, File, StreamWriter
      from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import TablePlot
      from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import DataPropertyClass
      from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import DataType
      from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Export import DataWriterTypeIdentifiers
      from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import DataPropertyClass
      from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import DataType
      from System.IO import File, Directory
      from System.IO import Path, File, StreamWriter
      from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import CrossTablePlot

      report1 = "C:\\export\\report1.csv"
      writer = StreamWriter(report1)

      Viz1.As[CrossTablePlot]().ExportText(writer)
```

I would like with the option to extract without value formatting.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Does this need to work on the web? That is where you will run into issues potentially.

Comment: @MarkP. no there is no need for the export process to be on the web

Answer (score 0):

Since your exporting as CSV and not xlsx or other Excel data type I would a script to export to csv and not use the built in function ExportText() as the final export.

https://community.tibco.com/wiki/how-export-tablecross-table-visualization-data-csv-file-using-tibco-spotfirer-using-ironpython has a good example where all the data is being writen to the csv file as strings.